# SPLimitedWebPartManger Exception : Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i got an exception when i'm trying to initilize the SPLimitedWebPartManager from SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager:
i think it does not accept the files inside _layouts folder, because i'm deplying this page containg web parts inside _layouts folder.

any help please.

```
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm =             
                  web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, 
                            PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                  {
                      foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart current in   
                       wpm.WebParts)
                      {
                          if (current is XsltListViewWebPart)
                          {
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the page would need to be GhostableInLibrary.  You would not be able to add web parts to a page stored on the file system.